# Convert Part of HTML code to svg using fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, html2canvas

Can I use fabricjs to convert part of Html code directly to svg file (without convert the HTML to canvas (using html2canvas) then canvas to svg) ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us some code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually I'm using html2canvas to convert html part to canvas then canvas to svg, but html2canvas contain an issue with rotate element doesn't good rendred, I create an example here : https://jsfiddle.net/bgw6o9sa/  , for this reason I'm asking if fabricjs can rendred HTML to svg without using html2canvas.